# On a centered element with a zoom scaling effect, how can I make so that the horizontal scroll bar scrolls to both sides?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Sorry if this is a silly question. I did quite some research before posting this but still couldn't figure it out.

I have an element with a basic zoom functionality using the scale effect.

When I increase the zoom to a point where the element overflows the screen horizontally, the horizontal scroll bar appears, as expected.

However, the scaling element overflows to both sides, and I can only scroll to the right.
I would like to be able to scroll to the left and right as well.

Here is the [CodeSandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/overflowing-centered-element-with-scale-and-scroll-r79vx2?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-48%2C1)

Here is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setZoom((prev) => prev + 0.1)}>
        increase zoom
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setZoom((prev) => prev - 0.1)}>
        decrease zoom
      </button>

      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: "10px",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            transform: `scale(${zoom})`,
            transformOrigin: "top center",
            width: "500px",
            height: "500px",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <span style={{ backgroundColor: "red", width: "100%" }}>
            left side
          </span>
          <span style={{ backgroundColor: "green", width: "100%" }}>
            center
          </span>
          <span style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", width: "100%" }}>
            right side
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

overflow: auto on the html or body or containing div of your columns

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the exact same behavior after doing that

Comment: you could increase the margin-left along with the zoom

Comment: But then it won't overflow centered anymore, it would overflow aligned to the left start. I could just use transform-origin: top left for that